# How can I Extract Japanese Text from a PDF using iTextSharp?

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, itext

This code returns lots of \0\0s and extracts only a few English phrases from the PDF. Any Japanese text is not returned.

I am using Unicode encoding, so I am not sure what is happening here.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(2000);
string fullFileName = @"c:\my_japanaese_pdf.pdf";
PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fullFileName);
for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
    currentText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(UnicodeEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(currentText)));
    text.Append(currentText);
}
pdfReader.Close();
```

(Windows 7 x64, iTextSharp 5.0.2.0)

Thanks

Ryan

Comment: Interesting that Console.WriteLine("節電対策") outputs ?????? in the console. Yet I have Japanese as a display language option in Control Panel, so assume I have native JP support on my PC. Riiiight?

Comment: That's one problem. The other problem is the iText(Sharp) version. It's way too old. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326767/difference-between-itextsharp-4-1-6-and-5-x-versions/ to find out what has changed since version 5.0.2 in the context of text extraction. I've also made a video that explains why some PDF don't allow you to extract text: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE Without seeing the PDF with the Japanese text, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Are you sure `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(UnicodeEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(currentText)))` does not break more than it fixes?

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie - not sure how I have an outdated copy, I'll redownload and also watch your video. So far this looks like a great library, thanks for providing it! If all works out (I can solve this JP extract issue) we'll look to incorporate to our project and license accordingly.

Comment: @Ryan, see this for what mkl is talking about. [Once you have a string, **you have a string**, and it is Unicode, **always**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10191879/231316)

Comment: Confession: this was a copy/paste from code elsewhere. I should've looked at that line more carefully. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. <suitably shamed>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading pdf  content using iTextSharp in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185643/reading-pdf-content-using-itextsharp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Good to hear, I'm going to flag this as a duplicate

Comment: Hmm, even after the upgrade and removal of the encoding, it still doesn't work. All Japanese text is simply removed. I can't see the YouTube video from work (!!!) will watch from home. As @BrunoLowagie points out, maybe it's 'just not possible'.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and here's what I did (note this code is extremely similar to the code in the question, but doesn't use any encoding conversion stuff).

```
using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(inputPDF))
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy Strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                string page = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, Strategy);
                string[] lines = page.Split('\n');
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    // do anything you want here
                }
            }
        }
```

Even when using the above code, I was still not getting any Japanese characters out of the PDF, so I **changed the font used in the PDF to Meiryo UI font**.  That is how to solve this problem.  **Meiryo UI** is a font that iTextSharp recognizes (at least version 5.5.13.2), so Japanese text with that font can successfully be extracted from the PDF.